# Reboot/poweroff an attached computer on reboot/poweroff of master system?

Tags: systemd, reboot

I have two computers (let's call them master and slave) connected via ethernet with static IP addressing.

What I want to achieve is to reboot slave whenever master is rebooted, and power it off whenever master is powered off.

Both systems are runinng Ubuntu Bionic with systemd.

So far I only concentrated on the rebooting. I created file `/lib/systemd/system/restart-jetson.service` with the following contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=Restart Jetson
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=systemd-reboot.service  # also tried just reboot.service
Requires=network.target
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/su -c 'echo "nvidia" | /usr/bin/ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no nvidia@%H-jetson "sudo -S reboot"' robot
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=reboot.target
```

Then I enabled the service with `systemctl enable restart-jetson.service` and `systemctl daemon-reload`.

SSH is configured for passwordless login on slave.

If I restart the service from a running system, slave is rebooted. However, rebooting the master system does nothing to the slave. How should I configure this systemd unit correctly?

Other SO posts or tutorials seem like this method should work, but for this particular use-case it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Is your question, “How do I run a program/script when my system goes down for reboot?”?

Comment: Okay, I'll clarify the quetsion. The fact is other commands can be run using services like this, but the problem is in this particular use-case nothing happens.